# В сторону(,) противоположную той улице

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Нужна ли запятая (та, что в скобочках)? Каким правилом руководствоваться в этом случае? Я нашла разные варианты: и [с запятой](https://books.google.ru/books?id=JctLDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA489&lpg=PA489&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=JASz4KmHzH&sig=ACfU3U0qcbRcgeymNMrZhunICQsOsFjYhQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv6pj-s7npAhXIk4sKHWRLDvYQ6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E&f=false), и [без неё](https://books.google.ru/books?id=41kvCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA469&lpg=PA469&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=0zj4YmtvyT&sig=ACfU3U1ZJIKPFm-EEaGxiTMuXVOOYde1pw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGvrKQp7npAhW0AxAIHb4uB44Q6AEwCXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E&f=false).

> На первом же перекрёстке мы свернули в сторону(,) противоположную той
>   улице, по которой я убегал вчера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая необходима. (В справочнике школьника, думаю, просто "недопечатка".)
**На первом же перекрёстке мы свернули в сторону, противоположную той улице, по которой я убегал вчера.**

В сторону (какую?) *противоположную* — это согласованное определение, выраженное прилагательным; распространенное (*противоположную той улице*).
Распространенное определение (причастие или **прилагательное с зависимыми словами**) обособляется, если стоит **после** определяемого существительного.
[**Обособление согласованных определений**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/714-233_obosoblenie_soglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)

*Сила упругости — сила, возникающая при деформации тела и направленная **в сторону, противоположную смещению его частиц,** вызванному деформацией...*
[Большая политехническая энциклопедия](https://books.google.ee/books?id=awO2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA458&lpg=PA458&dq=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=gIEm_9eJV2&sig=ACfU3U2CuWWV7Bdm98y_Ze8wjufdGsvroA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRw_PjubnpAhXLl4sKHQfQAOUQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false)

*Том и Сара покинули кабак, невзирая на погоду, и отправились в **сторону, противоположную той,** которую избрал Поножовщик* (Э. Сю. Парижские тайны).